# Converting a MySQL output from SELECT query to an UPDATE query

Tags: mysql

I accidentally screwed up a table I was maintaining. However before the screw up, I did a 'select * from tableName;' outputting everything in the table in a readable format and copied it to a txt file.

The table is unrecoverable and I did not do any transactions so I cannot rollback.

What I need to do is to convert the resulting output of the select query to an update or create table query so I can restore the current table to what it was like when I did the 'select * from tableName;' query.

I currently have the select query output stored on a text file, looking for a solution to this problem. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: It is not possible to do this by hand because the table contains well over hundreds of lines

Comment: Did you drop the table or just deleted/truncated it? If you don't have db/table backups then you can easily convert the text file into insert statements with some text editor to automate the construction of the statements.

Comment: I performed an update query which changed all of the column values for a table to a value which completely messed up my site. I could try that but the table in question is the wp_config from a wordpress site I maintain.

Comment: Why not truncate the table you messed up then load the flat file into the table? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/loading-tables.html

Comment: Is the site still online and the table being used? If this is the case you should stop the site or lock the table, take a backup and then try to restore the new data inserted after the "screw up" along with the data in your text file. Are you sure you don't have backups? If the records are just updated than you can construct update statements instead of insert statements. How does the text file look? A line representing a table row would be helpful.

Comment: If the file is in CSV format, you should be able to use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to load it back into the table.

Comment: BTW, I recommend using `mysqldump` to create a backup of a table before making changes. Then you can simply use `mysql < backupfile` to restore it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions regarding LOAD DATA INFILE, I have attempted to do the command, however it does not properly work as such some lines column values will be inserted for a specific number of characters then the rest of the column value will be dropped from the table. I suspect I am not doing it correctly. I used this command: `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "file.txt" INTO TABLE wp_options COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '|';`

Comment: Several example lines can be found at https://pastebin.com/yQnKm0Ss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the example lines [here](https://pastebin.com/yQnKm0Ss):

```
|         7 | start_of_week                                                      | 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                | yes      |
```

you can first discard all white spaces in the text file. On linux use the following `sed` command:
`sed 's/ \+//g' data.txt > data2.txt`

`data2.txt` will be your new text file without spaces. On windows you can use an advanced text editor to search-replace all white spaces in order to remove them.
With the text file now looking like this:

```
|7|start_of_week|1|yes|
|8|use_balanceTags|0|yes|
|9|use_smilies|1|yes|
```

use the following mysql command to load the data:

`mysql> load data infile 'data2.txt' replace into table wp_options fields terminated by '|' lines terminated by '|\n' starting by '|';`